# Reference to extension function?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to get reference to an extension function like you may do for usual function (see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references))?

I would expect the following code to compile, but now `::String.toSomething` is unknown:

```
fun String.toSomething() = length + 1
val some = listOf("lala", "bebebe").map(::String.toSomething)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Referencing extension methods in Kotlin can be done by applying the `::` operator between the class name and method name:

```
val function = Object::myExtensionMethod
```

so in your case:

```
fun String.toSomething() = length + 1
val some = listOf("lala", "bebebe").map(String::toSomething)
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean like this?

```
fun String.toSomething() = length + 1
val some = listOf("lala", "bebebe").map(String::toSomething)
```

Just remember to put `::` always before the function

Comment: The same syntax applies to member functions like `String::toUpperCase`

Answer (score 5):

OP defined an extension function as a standalone function. If regarding extension functions being **parts of another class**, then the reference is **impossible**. At least Intellij tells me so.

```
class MyClass {
  // This function cannot be referenced.
  fun Application.myExt() {
    return "value"
  }
}
```

As a workaround I did such thing:

```
class MyClass {
  fun getMyExtFunction: (Application.() -> Unit) {
    return {
      return "value"
    }
  }
}
```

Now instead of referencing a function, I return this function from another method. The outcome is the same.